# Is there a way mongoimport can return the number of inserted (distinct) rows

Tags: mongodb

I'm using `mongoimport` to upload a CSV file to my db collection and am also using `--upsertFields` to make sure there are no duplicated documents (rows) in the collection. My trouble is that I'm not able to say how many documents were actually imported because the only thing `mongoimport` returns is the total number of documents (rows) in my CSV file.

Is there a way to get the number of real inserts or duplicates from it?

Comment: Could you not run `db.getCollection('foo').find().count()` before hand, then subtract that from the output of `mongoimport`? There is nothing in the `man` to return the number of real inserts (from what I saw: `mongoimport version 2.2.2`)

Comment: Only way I've done similar is by increasing the verbosity and tail the log. -vvvvv

Comment: @hd: I thought about it but a little trouble is that if there's another process doing mongo import concurrently, I won't be able to calculate it reliably unless there is some way to wrap .count() and mongo import in a transaction. Any ideas?

Comment: @ry_donahue: I tried -vvvvv and it shows a lot of connection and parsing related things but still at the end says the total number of documents rather than the actual number of inserted ones.

Comment: ahh darn. sorry about that.